# How to install node http-server (with argument) as a service in windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, service

I trying to give access to local files through a webserver for VS2022's integrated edge; but there is a policy that prevents from accessing to local files, so I try to run a light web server as a service.

In a powershell, I can run a server with `http-server path/to/localfiles`. I can see that it's actually a powershell script with `get-command http-server`.

So I try to install a service with

```
new-service -name "http-server_vignettes" -binarypathname "http-server I:/C200_vignettes"
```

The installation succeeded: `get-service http-server_vignettes` returns

> ```
> Status   Name               DisplayName
> ------   ----               -----------
> Stopped  http-server_vigne… http-server_vignettes
> ```

But the service cannot start `start-service http-server_vignettes` returns

> ```
> Start-Service: Service 'http-server_vignettes (http-server_vignettes)'
> cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service
> 'http-server_vignettes' on computer '.'.
> ```

I checked that powershell is in the system's path, it is.

I tries other variants without success:

```
new-service -name "http-server_vignettes" -binarypathname "http-server.ps1 I:/C200_vignettes"
```

or

```
new-service -name "http-server_vignettes" -binarypathname "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\http-server.ps1 I:/C200_vignettes"
```

or

```
new-service -name "http-server_vignettes" -binarypathname "Start-Process PowerShell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\http-server.ps1 I:/C200_vignettes'"
```

How can I install such service ?